# How does virtualenv work?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I checked the *activate* script and it looks to me all it does is:

- set VIRTUAL_ENV env
- append $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin in front of PATH

How does `virtualenv` provide that magical virtual environment by these? What do I miss?

Comment: Don't forget about [virtualenv burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I will describe the basic process, which I learned from the presentation @jcollado linked to.

When Python starts, it looks at the path of the binary, and the prefixes thereof.

So let's say your virtualenv is `/home/blah/scratch`. The Python process knows it was executed from `/home/blah/scratch/bin/python` (which is usually just a copy of your system python binary `/usr/bin/python`) and it knows its own version `X.Y` because it's compiled into it. Then Python looks for `lib/pythonX.Y/os.py` in this order:

```
/home/blah/scratch/bin/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py
/home/blah/scratch/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py    <-- this file should exist
/home/blah/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py
/home/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py
/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py
```

It stops at `/home/blah/scratch/lib/pythonX.Y/os.py` because it's the first file that actually exists. If it didn't, Python would keep looking. It then sets `sys.prefix` based on this. It uses a similar process to set `sys.exec_prefix`, and then `sys.path` is constructed based on these.

Comment: `X.X` is derived from the Python version, so it'll be `2.7` or something similar.

Comment: Never thought about this path discovering for sys.prefix!

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining in the body of your answer rather than linking to an external source which could change or disappear in the future.

Comment: Before this answer, where is the doc stating all this? Even this was very hard to find.

Answer (score 22):

1. First the user creates a new virtualenv with the command `virtualenv myenv`. This creates a directory called *myenv* and copies the system python binary to *myenv/bin*. It also adds other necessary files and directories to *myenv*, including a setup script in *bin/activate* and a *lib* subdirectory for modules and packages.
2. Then the user sources the activate script with `. myenv/bin/activate`, which sets the shell’s `PATH` environment variable to start with *myenv/bin*.
3. Now when the user runs `python` from this shell, it will execute the copy of the binary stored in *myenv/bin*. Even though the binary is identical to the one in /usr/bin/python, the standard python binary is designed to search for packages and modules in directories that are relative to the binary’s path (this functionality is not related to virtualenv). It looks in *../lib/pythonX.Y* where X and Y are the major and minor version numbers of the python binary. So now it is looking in *myenv/lib/pythonX.Y*.
4. The *myenv/bin* directory also contains a script named `pip` so that when the user installs new packages using pip from the virtualenv, they will be installed in *myenv/lib/pythonX.Y*

Comment: I'm wondering where do you guys know the secret path looking of something like `../lib/pythonX.Y` and even other stuff related to `sys.prefix` and etc?

Comment: I haven't seen any good documentation about it yet, but I noticed this behavior when building Python from source. You can also test it like this: `mkdir /tmp/bin; mkdir /tmp/lib; cp /usr/bin/python /tmp/bin; cp -r /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/ /tmp/lib/pythonX.Y; /tmp/bin/python`. Then type `import sys; sys.prefix`. This will show "/tmp". If you remove the /tmp/lib directory, it will revert to "/usr".

Comment: Step 3 is the key thing I was missing--that the python binary looks in it's executable's neighborhood for associated files.  Thanks.