# How to run Orange3 after Installing?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, orange

I am trying to install and run Orange3 on my ubuntu 15.10 machine. I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/biolab/orange3) and installed Orange3.
After the installation, When I run

```
python3 -m Orange.canvas
```

This command, It opens up Orange GUI and works perfectly. But when I try to open the Orange in next time It didn't work. It shows

> /usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'Orange.canvas' (: No module named 'scipy')

This error msg. I try to install Orange again and try whether it work. It runs first time, but next time It gives this error message. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The couple of lines in the instructions indicate you created a separate virtual environment for Orange package. I quote:

> ```
> # Create a separate Python environment for Orange and its dependencies,
> # and make it the active one
> virtualenv --python=python3 --system-site-packages orange3venv
> source orange3venv/bin/activate
> ```

This means you should now always run

```
source orange3venv/bin/activate  # inside where your orange3env dir is
```

before running `python -m Orange.canvas`. See [How does virtualenv work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427709/how-does-virtualenv-work)

Alternatively, you can use the path to Python interpreter inside the virtual environment:

```
orange3venv/bin/python -m Orange.canvas
```

This should work as well. You can paste it all into a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
/full/path/to/.../orange3venv/bin/python -m Orange.canvas
```

mark the script executable

```
chmod +x run-orange.sh
```

and then when you double-click it, it should run Orange GUI for you.