# How virtual environments work in python (internally)

Tags: python, virtualenv

Hi could someone explain how virtual environments work, what happens exactly under the hood (internally)? there aren’t many resources online that explain it clearly.I read Artem Golubin’s blog but cannot understand it.I would be extremely grateful if someone could help ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does virtualenv work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427709/how-does-virtualenv-work)

Comment: you can consider it as, a seperate python environment is installed in the virtualenv directory, which work when you activate/deactivate that python env or your program access that environment. internally it is same as python env installed in your system.

Answer (score 3):

A virtual environment is just another installation of Python. Your "main" environment might be `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/lib/python3.7`, and your virtual environment might be installed under `~/venv/bin/python` and `~/venv/lib/python3.9`. You can use either one as long as you specify the correct Python executable.

You can *activate* a virtual environment by setting your `PATH` and environment variable to prefer the virtual environment over the main environment. That's virtually all `~/venv/bin/activate` does. It also defines a `deactivate` shell function that lets you deactivate your virtual environment, restoring your `PATH` to the value it had when you sourced `activate`.